# How to stop td / tr from taking up all available height?

Tags: html, css, layout, height, css-tables

I set the height of my table to a specific height so I could use `overflow-y: scroll` on it, and this caused the `td`s to expand to fill all the available height. I have tried changing height to `max-content`, as well as set values such as `1rem` however nothing changes the height of them.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                width: 100%;
                height: 20rem;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Test Column</th>
                    <th>Test Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test Data</td>
                    <td>Test Data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: @Pete Sorry about that - forgot to include one! There you go :)

Comment: all you have to do is remove the height then you should get what you want?

Comment: @Pete That isn't what I want though - I want to keep the table height so that I can use overflow-y: scroll on it as well as have it take up a fixed height on the page

Comment: You can't. If you give the table a specific height, the cells will fill that space.

Comment: shove it in a div with that height and then give the table a max height of 100%